# angularjs translate-value to get the value from i18n file

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have the following html code to get angular to translate the label from `dash.title` and the span text from `errors.correct`.

```
<label translate="dash.title"></label>
<span class="success text-small" translate="errors.correct" translate-values="{ fieldname: 'dash.title' | translate }"></span>
```

my `errors.correct`in the i18n file is like this:

```
"errors": {
    "correct": "The « {{fieldname}} » is correctly filled out!"
  }
```

so my `fieldname` has to get the value from the `label`, it should be the same as the label text. 
Why this setup is not working? what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
translate-values="{ fieldname:'{{'dash.title' | translate}}' }"
```